# Need clarification on cmd, powershell, developer command prompt etc

Tags: powershell

those things all have a window for me to type commands in. it has been a while but i still don't know what are the differences. can someone clarify please? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is (a) not about programming per se, and (b) very broad. At this level of abstraction, Wikipedia articles may be your best friend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a good site pointing out some of the main differences. http://www.howtogeek.com/163127/how-powershell-differs-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Esentially:

Cmd - Your typical windows command prompt that has been around for a long time.

Developer Cmd - Do you mean administrator cmd? If so, it's the same as cmd with elevated privleges that you would usually type in your password for.

Powershell - A new take on the windows command prompt that has slightly different commands and increased functionality.